# F# Beginner: retrieving an array of data from a server

Tags: mysql, database, f#

I'm trying to grab data from a MySQL database.

Approach 2 - apply/map style

I'm using the [MySQL ADO Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html) to try to build this system. In particular, the example found at 21.2.3.1.7.

(using a pseudo code)

```
let table = build_sequence(query.read)
```

Where query.read returns a row in the table(Or rather, a list of elements that happen to be a row in the table). And the table variable is a list of lists that will represent a table returned from the query.

I've stared at the code given below, and it's syntax is over my head, I'm afraid.

Approach 1 - looping.

Problem 1: It's inelegant, requiring a mutable.

Problem 2: This just *feels* wrong, based on my prior experience with Prolog & Lisp. There's gotta be a more...*functional* way to do this.

I'm not sure where to begin though. Comments & thoughts?

```
let reader : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

let arr = []

let mutable rowIter = 0
let readingLoop() =
    while(reader.Read()) do
        rowIter = rowIter + 1
        for i = 0 to reader.FieldCount do

            //set arr[someiterator, i] = reader.GetValue[i].ToString())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Seq type has a neat function for handling database cursors called generate_using (see [F# Manual](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/FSharp.PowerPack/Microsoft.FSharp.Compatibility.Seq.html) and the Data Access chapter in [Foundations of F#](http://apress.com/book/view/9781590597576)). This is a higher order function that takes one function to open the cursor and another (called repeatedly) to process records from the cursor. Here is some code that uses generate_using to execute a sql query:

```fs
let openConnection (connectionName : string) =
    let connectionSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item(connectionName)
    let connectionString = connectionSetting.ConnectionString
    let connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    connection

let generator<'a> (reader : IDataReader) =
    if reader.Read() then
        let t = typeof<'a>
        let props = t.GetProperties()
        let types = props
                    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.PropertyType)
                    |> Seq.to_array
        let cstr = t.GetConstructor(types)
        let values = Array.create reader.FieldCount (new obj())
        reader.GetValues(values) |> ignore
        let values = values
                     |> Array.map (fun x -> match x with | :? DBNull -> null | _ -> x)
        Some (cstr.Invoke(values) :?> 'a)
    else
        None

let executeSqlReader<'a> (connectionName : string) (sql : string) : 'a list =        
    let connection = openConnection connectionName

    let opener() = 
        let command = connection.CreateCommand(CommandText = sql, CommandType = CommandType.Text)
        command.ExecuteReader()

    let result = Seq.to_list(Seq.generate_using opener generator)        

    connection.Close()
    connection.Dispose()
    result
```

For example to list all the tables in an Oracle database we need to define a column definition type and invoke executeSqlReader as follows:

```fs
type ColumnDefinition = {
    TableName : string;
    ColumnName : string;
    DataType : string;
    DataLength : decimal;                
}

let tableList = executeSqlReader<ColumnDefinition>
    "MyDatabase"
    "SELECT t.table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length FROM USER_TABLES t, USER_TAB_COLUMNS c where t.TABLE_NAME = c.table_name order by t.table_name, c.COLUMN_NAME"
```

Comment: OK. I'm still not totally comfortable with all the syntactic elements in that, but I follow the semantics and it answers my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd use the *use* keyword to dispose the connection instead of doing it manually.

Comment: After time has passed, I still can't get the syntax to sort itself out.

Answer (score 3):

It can be hard to work with imperative APIs in a non-imperative way.  I don't have MySql handy, but I made an approxmiation, hopefully this will provide inspiration.  Seq.unfold is a function people find pretty awesome once they grok it.  List.init (or Array.init) are also handy for initializing known-size data structures without using mutables.

```
#light

type ThingLikeSqlReader() =
    let mutable rowNum = 0
    member this.Read() =
        if rowNum > 3 then
            false
        else
            rowNum <- rowNum + 1
            true
    member this.FieldCount = 5
    member this.GetValue(i) = i + 1

let reader = new ThingLikeSqlReader()    
let data = reader |> Seq.unfold (fun (reader : ThingLikeSqlReader) ->
    if reader.Read() then
        Some (List.init reader.FieldCount (fun i -> reader.GetValue(i)), reader)
    else
        None) |> Seq.to_list 
printfn "%A" data
```