# F# error: Wrong number of parameters

Tags: f#

I am puzzling over some code given to me in a prior SO question I had. [Code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/f-beginner-retrieving-an-array-of-data-from-a-server#295788)

At this line, I get an error saying I have an invalid number of parameters. I don't completely understand what the error is, since all the research I do comes up with this being a correct application of the function.

```
let result = Seq.to_list(Microsoft.FSharp.Compatibility.Seq.generate_using opener generator)
```

What's going on here? Why am I getting this kind of error?

Edit: I use the PowerPack.dll reference and the MySQL.Data reference

Code for opener & generator below:

```
 let opener() = 
        let command = connection.CreateCommand(CommandText = sql, CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text)
        command.ExecuteReader()
```

And generator...

```
let generator<'a> (reader : System.Data.IDataReader) =
    if reader.Read() then
        let t = typeof<'a>
        let props = t.GetProperties()
        let types = props
                    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.PropertyType)
                    |> Seq.to_array
        let cstr = t.GetConstructor(types)
        let values = Array.create reader.FieldCount (new obj())
        reader.GetValues(values) |> ignore
        let values = values
                     |> Array.map (fun x -> match x with | :? System.DBNull -> null | _ -> x)
        Some (cstr.Invoke(values) :?> 'a)
    else
        None
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the type of opener and generator here - what types do they have when you hover over them?

Comment: opener/generator are in the link

Comment: Yes, but I don't have Sql installed and/or don't know what Assembly references I need to add and namespaces I need to open to make that all compile.  And people rarely follow links to find your code.  Please put all the relevant info for this question in this question.

Comment: Mausch, I get a run-time error for some reason.

Comment: sorry, I thought the code didn't type-check.

Comment: It's a run-time error saying "invalid # of params".

Answer (score 1):

This post is old and languishing, but are you sure the invalid number of parameters error isn't coming from the Oracle command?

Basically: are you specifying a parameter in the SQL query? The opener function is not applying any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following type checks for me:

```
#light
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient
open System.Configuration


type Employee =
    { FirstName: string;
      LastName: string; }

let generator<'a> (reader: IDataReader) =
    if reader.Read() then
        let t = typeof<'a>
        let props = t.GetProperties()
        let types = props
                    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.PropertyType)
                    |> Seq.to_array
        let cstr = t.GetConstructor(types)
        let values = Array.create reader.FieldCount (new obj())
        reader.GetValues(values) |> ignore
        let values = values
                     |> Array.map (fun x -> match x with | :? System.DBNull -> null | _ -> x)
        Some (cstr.Invoke(values) :?> 'a)
    else
        None

let opener() = 
    let sql = "select * from employees"
    let connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["myConnection"].ConnectionString)
    let command = connection.CreateCommand(CommandText = sql, CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text)
    command.ExecuteReader()

let result = Seq.to_list(Microsoft.FSharp.Compatibility.Seq.generate_using opener (generator<Employee>))
```

It looks like your missing a type annotation to tell the generator what type of list your generating ie: `generator<Employee>`

Comment: Doing that gets me: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\fsharp1\Program.fs(56,5): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
   'a list
  but given a
   ColumnDefinition list.
  The type ''a' does not match the type 'ColumnDefinition'.